# Rotate bits in cryptography

Tags: c, cryptography, bit-shift

I need explanation what exaclty means this operation in C language.

I know this is doing a bit shift to left by n, but I don't understand this code:

```
| (a >> (32 - n)).
```

This is full code below:

```
uint32_t rot_l(uint32_t a, uint8_t n)
{
    return (a << n) | (a >> (32 - n));
}
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Some processors have a rotate instruction, but C does not implement it: the shifted bits "fall off the end" and vanish. So before they do, they are collected and shifted *right* to where they should be, and ORred with the remaining bits that were shifted left.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is this 32 in any way connected to difference of ASCII value between big and small letter?

Comment: No, it is the number of bits in the type `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Given a sample 32 bit integer a:

```
11000000001111111110000000000000
```

a << n will shift the entire sequence to the left by n bits. Any bits that are shifted to the left of the first bit are removed. Any new bits added on the right are 0. So, say we shift this by n = 3, we'll get:

```
00000001111111110000000000000000
```

Then, a >> (32 - n) will shift a to the right by 32 - n. Note that 32 is the size in bits of a, so 32 - n will shift all the bits that didn't get truncated to the right. For n = 3 again, we'll get:

```
00000000000000000000000000000110
```

(the 110 is the first 3 most significant bits of n)

Finally, the `|` is the bitwise or operator, and this will compute the result of every using or on every bit in the two results.

```
00000001111111110000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000110
================================ |
00000001111111110000000000000110
```

So what happens is, first the bits of a are shifted to the left by n. This results in the n most significant bits being truncated. Then these n most signifcant bits are shifted all the way to the right, to fill up the space that was originally filled with 0 from the left shift.
The result is then combined using the |. This simulates the entire string of bits in the integer being rotated to the left. This makes sense given the name of the function is `rot_l` :)

Comment: Thank You so much!!